# Reshaping df into data panel model

Tags: r

I have the following sets of data:

```
df1 <- data.frame( country = c("A", "B","A","B"), year = c(2011,2011,2012,2012), variable_1= c(1,3,5,7))    

df2 <- data.frame( country = c("A", "B","A","B"), year = c(2011,2012,2012,2013), variable_2= c(2,4,6,8))

df3 <- data.frame( country = c("A", "C","C"), year = c(2011,2011,2013), variable_3= c(9,9,9))
```

I want to reshape them into a panel data model, so I can get the following result:

```
df4 <- data.frame( country = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"), year = c(2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013), variable_1 = c(1,5,NA,3,7,NA,NA,NA,NA), variable_2 = c(2,6,NA,NA,4,8,NA,NA,NA), variable_3 = c(9,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,9,NA,9) )
```

I have searched for this info, but the topics I found ([Reshaping panel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352779/reshaping-panel-data)) didn´t help me.

Any ideas on how to do that? My real data sets have thousands of lines ("countries"), several variables, years and NA´s, so please take that into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Reduce(full_join, list(df1, df2, df3)) %>% 
  complete(country, year)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
#
#  country  year variable_1 variable_2 variable_3
#    (chr) (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
#1       A  2011          1          2          9
#2       A  2012          5          6         NA
#3       A  2013         NA         NA         NA
#4       B  2011          3         NA         NA
#5       B  2012          7          4         NA
#6       B  2013         NA          8         NA
#7       C  2011         NA         NA          9
#8       C  2012         NA         NA         NA
#9       C  2013         NA         NA          9
```

Comment: I just discovered Reduce myself, I'm glad you reminded me of it here. I think you can just do `Reduce(full_join, list(df1, df2, df3)) %>% complete(country, year)`.

Comment: You're right. It could be simplified. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Nice solution. Useful new function added to `tidyr`

Comment: I couldn´t reproduce you code; I´m getting a error related to the " %>%". Since I´m quite a beginner, I assume I´m doing something wrong... (Error: could not find function "%>%")

Comment: @Gil33 You have to load the packages

Comment: I hadn´t installed the correct packages, now it worked just fine. Thanks a lot!